# PHP Date Selector

Tags: php

I've made the following date selector in PHP for a timetable but when i use it, it starts at the start of PHP time (1970). How do I make it show the current date?

```
//date selector
$weekStart = 1;
$date =  date('Y').'-'. date('m').'-'. date('d');
$timestamp = strtotime($date);

$dayOfWeek = date('N', $timestamp);

echo("<br><br><form action='' name='timetable' method='Post'><div style='position:relative;left:40%;'><h4>Select Week Beginning</h4></div><div style='float:middle;position:relative;left:39%;'><select onchange='submit();' name='date'>");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $startDate = mktime(0,0,0, date('n', $timestamp), date('j', $timestamp) - $dayOfWeek + $weekStart + ( $i * 7), date('Y', $timestamp));
    if(date('d-m-Y', $startDate) == $_POST['date']){
       $selected = "selected='selected'";
    }
    else{
       $selected = "";
    };
    echo("<option ".$selected." >". date('d-m-Y', $startDate)."</option>");
}

echo('</select></form></div><br>');
echo("<table style='border:1px solid;'>");
    $weekStart = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['date'])){
        $timestamp = strtotime($_POST['date']);
    }else{
        $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    };

for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $dayrow = mktime(0,0,0, date('n', $timestamp), date('j', $timestamp) - $dayOfWeek + $weekStart + $i , date('Y', $timestamp));
    echo("<td style='text-align:left;width:800px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;'><h4>".date('D j-m-Y', $dayrow)."</h4></td>");
    echo("<td >");
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Code works fine and starts today. Maybe you want to check your system clock on the machine that runs your PHP.

Comment: Note: I added the closing ``}`` on the last line in my test.

Comment: Your code is definitely good. I also ran it and got the correct date. got to be server time